# Динамическая подгрузка каталога товаров

Tags: modx, ajax, php

Добрый день всем!

Есть такой вопрос: как можно осуществить динамическую подгрузку контента? Например, вызывается сниппет msProducts, в котором загружается, например, элементов 10, внизу должно сработать событие по скроллеру или по кнопке подгрузить еще 10 элементов. То, что это с использованием скрипта на ajax будет, понятно. Волнует другое - как в запросе избежать прямого обращения к базе данных?

Например, идет вызов внешнего файла:

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'load.php',
         method: 'GET',
         data: {"num" : num},
         beforeSend: function() {
           inProcess = true;
         }
       })
```

Потом в файле load.php идет обращение к базе данных:

```
$num = $_GET['num'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT {$num}, 10");
$news = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $news[] = $row;
}
```

В условиях, что мы работает не с чистым php, а modx, хотел спросить, как решаются такие задачи в этой CMS? Спасибо всем за внимание к моему вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Безумкина есть [AjaxSnippet](https://bezumkin.ru/sections/components/2557/#tab=tab-tickets).
А вот [здесь](http://modx.ws/urok-modx-ajax-zagruzka-resursov) хорошая статья по работе с Ajax в MODX (посмотрите демо).

Comment: Да это именно то что надо). Спасибо!